# Search Command without using WHERE CLAUSE while connected to sqldatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

the problem is i can use my database if my gridview is not connected to database using sqldatasource 
it will work if my database is connected manually using code to gridview

i need a code to search my data using datagrid and textbox and button with the search code in it

here's my current code for search command 
but its only working when i connect my datagrid to database manually using code

```
strconn = "select * from User_TBL_DB where (Lastname like '%' + @search +'%')";
            SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(strconn, conn);
            xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = SearchBOX.Text;

            conn.Open();

            xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = xp;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Name");

            GridView2.DataSource = ds;
            GridView2.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
```

hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

SQL Command is not correct. It should be `... LIKE '%@Search%'`

```
var ds = new DataSet();
using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
{
    string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM User_TBL_DB WHERE Lastname LIKE '%@Search%'";
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, cnn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", SearchBOX.Text);

    cnn.Open();

    var da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

    da.Fill(ds, "Name");
}

GridView2.DataSource = ds;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

Comment: It give me this error

"Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition."

maybe because my datagrid is connected to sqldatasource1

Comment: Yes, correct. You can need to remove DataSourceID if you use DataSource.